# AttributeError: partially initialized module 'cv2' has no attribute 'VideoCapture' w/installed opencv-contrib-python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, spyder, opencv, security-camera

'''Below is the code that I am trying to run. I am getting the AttributeError. I have python 3.6.6 and I cannot import cv2. I will get an error: "AttributeError: partially initialized module 'cv2' has no attribute 'VideoCapture' (most likely due to a circular import)".

Is the path correct?
It is being executed from Users/"User directory name"/.spyder-py3/cv2.py'''

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import cv2
#print(cv2._file_)
# open import video
video_capture=cv2.VideoCapture('video.mp4')
# webcam: video_capture=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
#read first frame
_, current_frame= video_capture.read()
cv2.imshow('app', current_frame)
cv2.waitKey(0)
video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```